# Python Algorithm Analysis

Tags: python, algorithm

Determine the exact number of times
BigFn() is called.

```
for i in range(1,N+1):
   for j in range(1,N*N+1):
      myList[i][j] = BigFn(i,j)
```

This is what I'm guessing.

```
for i in range(1,N+1): # N times
   for j in range(1,N*N+1): # N^2 times
      myList[i][j] = BigFn(i,j) #Here is where I don't know what to do...?
```

And how do I figure out the best and worst case behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We also don't know. What does BigFn do?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the question. How many times is BigFn called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your guesses are correct and bigFn() is called **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** times. As you said :

```
for i in range(1,N+1): # N times
   for j in range(1,N*N+1): # N^2 times
```

so based on [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), BigFn() is called **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** times.

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: @MurrayS it is very basic mathematics, and it called rule of product.

Comment: That's for changing your answer. And would there be anyway to find out best case behaviour and worst case behaviour?

Comment: There is no best case or worst case, best case and worst case have a meaning when behavior may change regarding to input, but in your case, you always iterate between 1 to n+1 and 1 to n*n + 1. so there is no best case or worst case, bigFn is always called O(n^3).